# Cannot find certain Windows domain users

Tags: active-directory, domain, windows-server-2016, windows-service, windows-server-essentials

I see a service runnuing on my Windows Server Essentials 2016 domain controller  with user name "MediaAdmin$":

[image]

However, when I'm searching for this user in my AD, there are no results:

[image]

I'm looking for this user, because I want to change its password. How is it possible that it runs a process, although it's not available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a computer account, not a user account. The `$` at the end of the username marks it as a computer account. Change your search parameters to search for Computers instead of Users, Groups and Contacts and you will find it.

Comment: This works. Nevertheless I wonder, why they would name a computer "..:Admin"

Comment: More specifically, it's a managed service account.